# Can we create SQL Server Alias for existing SP 2013 environment?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sql-alias

Can we create a SQL Alias for already existing SharePoint 2013 environment? If so what the necessary steps to be taken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however the Admin/Config connection string cannot change. This means the alias name must match the in-use SQL Server name (or name\instance). You can set the alias up via `cliconfg.exe`.